# Как написать проверку поля forms.IntegerField чтобы значение не уходило в минус?

Tags: django, form, валидация

Подскажите как написать проверку поля `forms.IntegerField` чтобы значение не уходило в минус. Суть моей формы, что авторизованный пользователь может выбрать в поле `account_1` счет от куда перевести, а в поле `account_2` куда перевести средства. Поле `amount` это сколько перевести. Вот класс формы.

```
forms.py
class TransfersForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(TransfersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['account_1'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)
    self.fields['account_2'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)

account_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='С какого счёта')
account_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='На какой счёт')
amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Сумма перевода')

def clean_account_1(self): # это поле с которого нужно сделать перевод
    form_amount = self.cleaned_data.get('amount')
    form_account_1 = self.cleaned_data.get('account_1') # здесь получаю из формы с какого счета
    account_db = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user, account=form_account_1) # сюда получаю из БД счёт пользователя
    if account_db[0].account_balance.balance-form_amount < 0: # здесь хочу сделать проверку, что если счёт ушел в минус то выдать ошибку
        raise ValidationError('Недостаточно средств на счёте')
        
    return form_account_1
```

Но Джанго ни как не реагирует на эту валидацию и баланс на счете все равно уходит в минус. Подскажите, что я делаю не так.

Счета пользователь создает при помощи модели `Bank_Account`, а при создании автоматически создается баланс к счёту при помощи модели `Account_Balance`

```
models.py
class Bank_Account (models.Model):
account_choices = (
    ('USD', 'USD'),
    ('EUR', 'EUR'),
    ('RUB', 'RUB'),
)
account = models.CharField(choices=account_choices, max_length=3, verbose_name='Счёт')
time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
client = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Клиент')

def __str__(self):
    return self.account

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('add_balance', kwargs={'account_balance_pk': self.pk})
        
def del_account_url(self):
    return reverse('del_account', kwargs={'account_pk': self.pk})
    
class Meta: 
    verbose_name = 'Банковские счета'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Банковские счета' 
    ordering = ['time_create']
    
class Account_Balance (models.Model):
bank_account = models.OneToOneField(Bank_Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')

def __str__(self):
    return self.balance
        
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Баланс счёта'
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bank_Account)
def create_user_bank_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Account_Balance.objects.create(bank_account=instance)
        
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bank_Account)
def save_user_bank_account(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.account_balance.save()
```

Comment: Добвьте к описанию вопроса модель `Bank_Account`, а вообще в строке `if account_db[0].account_balance.balance < 0:` наверно можно сделать вычитание form_amount, а то я так понимаю, оно у вас проверяет баланс еще до вычитания суммы

Comment: @maestro, да Вы правы вычитание нужно сделать, оно у меня изначально было, но когда пробовал кучу разных вариантов куда-то потерялось. Добавил вычитание теперь выдает ошибку **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'NoneType'** т.е. я не могу чтоле обращаться к  переменной 'account_db' как к экземпляру, пробовал в оболочке 'shell' он выводил меня на поле с балансом. Здесь почему то не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился так (спасибо незнакомцу из чата Telegram).
В `models.py` в классе `Account_Balance` поле `balance` заменил на `models.PositiveIntegerField()`.
Теперь при попытке перевода средств со счет на счет, если баланс уходит в минус то выдается ошибка `IntegrityError` и Django`вская страница с трассировкой. Я думаю, что эту ошибку можно перехватывать и выводить, что-то свое, но цель достигнута значение поля не уходит в минус.
Вот код по итогу:

```
forms.py
class TransfersForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(TransfersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['account_1'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)
    self.fields['account_2'].queryset = Bank_Account.objects.filter(client=self.user)

account_1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='С какого счёта')
account_2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None, label='На какой счёт')
amount = forms.IntegerField(label='Сумма перевода', validators=[validators.MinValueValidator(0),])

def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['account_1'] == self.cleaned_data['account_2']:
        raise ValidationError('Перевод невозможен. Выбраны одинаковые счета')
            
def clean_amount(self):
    form_amount = self.cleaned_data.get('amount')
    if form_amount > 1000:
        raise ValidationError('Сумма перевода должна быть меньше 1000')
        
    return form_amount
```

В `models.py` изменился только класс `Account_Balance`

```
models.py
class Account_Balance (models.Model):
bank_account = models.OneToOneField(Bank_Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Баланс')

def __str__(self):
    return self.balance
    
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('add_balance', kwargs={'account_balance_pk': self.pk})

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Баланс счёта'
    
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bank_Account)
def create_user_bank_account(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Account_Balance.objects.create(bank_account=instance)
        
@receiver(post_save, sender=Bank_Account)
def save_user_bank_account(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.account_balance.save()
```